# When 2 int's are stored in Visual Studio, the difference between their locations comes out to be 12 bytes. Is there a reason for this?

Tags: visual-c++

When I run the following program in VC++ 2008 Express, I get the difference in location between two consecutively stored integers as '12' instead of expected '4'. On any other compilers, the answer comes out to be '4'. Is there a particular reason for why '12'?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1, num2;
    cin >> num1 >> num2;
    cout << &num1 << endl << &num2 << endl;
    cout << int(&num1) - int(&num2)<<endl; //Here it shows difference as 12.
    cout << sizeof(num1);                  //Here it shows the size as 4.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you show all the output?  I'd be interested in seeing the actual pointer values.

Comment: Just wondering, does stack grow up or down in memory with Visual C++? I am asking cause should it be "int(&num1) - int(&num2)" or "int(&num2) - int(&num1)"

Comment: Is this really an issue  - does the C++ spec state that stack variables are to be adjacent AND the difference in memory locations is to be the size of the type?

Comment: @Tim:  The C++ spec says nothing about this.  However, it's a natural way to implement local variables.  This is curiosity about how the compiler lays out storage, not any sort of conformance problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to make a wild guess and say that you built it in debug mode. Try building it in release mode and see what you get. I know the C++ run-time will place memory guards around allocated memory in debug mode to catch buffer overflows. I don't know if it does something similar with variables on the stack.

Comment: Here is the output as requested: 
0034F890
0034F884
12
4Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Yup. For me, debug gives 12, release gives -4.

Comment: May be a difference in the express version of VS2008. I get 12 in debug mode and -4 in release mode (VS2008 Professional SP1).

Comment: It would be nice to know *why* this specific value of 12 bytes is used in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

You could be developing code for a computer in China or it may be that there is a small and rare deficiency in the specific hardware you are using. One old model has difficulty with large numbers where the top bits become set and if the variables are in contiguous memory locations it was found that a buildup of charge in the core memory could have a crosseffect on adjacent memory locations and alter the contents. Other possibilities are spare memory locations for detecting overflows and underflows and it could be that you are running 32bit software mapped onto a 48bit hardware architecture brought forward to exist as a new model with the spare bits and bytes remaining unused.

Comment: This would be a much more interesting answer if you provided references; as it is now it just seems pretty far-fetched.